# Amazon linux unable to boot post kernel update to 5.10

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, linux-kernel, amazon-linux

I'm using amazon linux 2 with kernel 4.14.314-238.539.amzn2.x86_64
I tried upgrading the kernel to kernel 5.10 using the following command:
`sudo amazon-linux-extras install kernel-5.10 -y`

Post kernel upgrade when I reboot the instance it's failing to boot with the following logs:

````
[  200.439712] dracut-initqueue[1518]: Warning: dracut-initqueue timeout - starting timeout scripts
[  200.441058] dracut-initqueue[1518]: Warning: Could not boot.
[  200.441894] dracut-initqueue[1518]: Warning: /dev/xvda2 does not exist
         Starting Setup Virtual Console...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Setup Virtual Console.
Warning: /dev/xvda2 does not exist

Generating "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt"


Entering emergency mode. Exit the shell to continue.
Type "journalctl" to view system logs.
You might want to save "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt" to a USB stick or /boot
after mounting them and attach it to a bug report.```


Any pointers/fix will be much appreciated! 

Tried installing version 5.4 as well and still getting the same error.
````